# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 table called `Prac1` and `prac2`.`Prac1` has trigger.When insertion happen in `prac1`,same entry goes in `prac2`(trigger code).I have made one sp,in that selecting top 3 id from `prac1` and inserting again into `prac1` with it's value(other column).But only one row get added not 3.Query is:

```
Insert name,lname into prac1 where id in(select top3 id from prac1).
```

When I am removing trigger,my sp get executed and 3 entry get added into table.How to handle this situation?

> prac1:Id,Name,Lname
>   prac2:Name,Lname

Comment: Sounds like your trigger is broken. A common mistake to only handle single row changes. Post your trigger code.

Comment: Huh? The query provided is not syntactically valid.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your query is working? Because as already stated on a comment, the syntax is not valid. Take a look into [MSDN for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms174633%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) The correct syntax is:

```
INSERT [INTO] 
      table_name  [ ( column_list ) ] 
      { VALUES 
      ( { DEFAULT | NULL | expression } [ ,...n] ) 
| derived_table
       }
```

So your insert query should something like:

```
INSERT INTO prac1(name, lname) 
SELECT TOP 3 name, lname
  FROM prac1
```

Post your trigger code, the line you see inserted should be the first one that triggers the trigger. Nevertheless, the inserts could trigger it again. So maybe you will need to disable it and reenable it.